# BackgroundDownloader can't write file to SD card (WP8.1)

Tags: download, background, windows-phone-8.1

Sorry for my bad English...
My application downloads the MP3-files and writes them to musicLibrary. Downloading files performed through BackgroundDownloader. The problem is the following: downloading is completed without problems in the internal phone memory, but is not completed on the SD-card. File on the SD-card has a size of 0 bytes. 
In the manifest, the application has permission to internetClientServer, musicLibrary and removableStorage.

```
public async void HandleSelectDownload(string urlDownload, string fileNameSave)
    {
        try
        {
            // Thông số tải nhạc
            var requestUri = new Uri(urlDownload, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

            downloadTo = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync(fileNameSave, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
            DownloadOperation operation = downloader.CreateDownload(requestUri, downloadTo);

            //progressbar
            Progress<DownloadOperation> downloadProgress = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(DownloadProgress);
            // start download
            await operation.StartAsync().AsTask(downloadProgress);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine("HandleSelectDownload Error : \n" + ex); }
    }

    public void DownloadProgress(DownloadOperation operation)
    {
        try
        {
            if (operation.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive == 0) return;

            int progress = (int)(100 * ((double)operation.Progress.BytesReceived / (double)operation.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive));

            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} of {1} kb. downloaded - %{2} complete.", operation.Progress.BytesReceived / 1024, operation.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024, progress));

            if (progress >= 100)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Finish!: {0} ", operation.ResultFile.Name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine("DownloadProgress Error :" + ex); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Windows 8/8.1, and it has been [fixed in Windows 10](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/02/networking-api-improvements-in-windows-10/). No API changes. Just try running your app in a Windows 10 device.